# Windows Phone 8 Web Browser Javascript not Working

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8

This code working on desktop browser but not work windows phone 8 web browser.
Can some one help me please

```
function loadMoreHome() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'loadmore.php',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',

        error: function(){
            console.log('Error');
        },
        success: function (data) {

           $('#moreNews').append(data);
        }

    });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {               
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).innerHeight()) {
            loadMoreHome();
        }
});
```

Comment: Please explain more about exactly what your problem is.  'not working' isn't enough to tell us what the problem is.  Do you get an error?  Does nothing happen when something should happen, and if so, what?

Comment: @Upvoter: care to explain why? This is a question that basically says "it's not working here's my code" without any attempt to explain what the code should be doing and why the questioner considers that it isn't working.

Comment: i want to windows phone 8 html5 app load more content with ajax, and this is my code, it is working all borwser but  windows phone 8  web browser not working and i tryed IsScriptEnabled = true; but not working

Comment: You still haven't explained what 'not working' means.  For example, do you get an error message (and if so, what)?  Or do you just scroll to the bottom, expect more content to load but no content actually does load?

Answer (score 0):

For the WebBrowsertask, we have to enable scripting like this.

WebBrowsertask1.IsScriptEnabled = true;